# Navigation from splash screen to the mainpage.xaml causes a small jump?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, splash-screen

While running the app on device, I noticed that there is a small jump while navigating from the splash screen to the MainPage.xaml.

I don understand why it jumps, Is it aligning the UI elements and layouts? There is an appbar in the MainPage.xaml, anything related to it?

How can I ensure smooth transition from the spash screen to the mainpage.xaml?

Alfah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an image as a background of your main page and you want it to match the splash screen image you need to consider 3 things:

1. Splash screen image is loaded by the OS. Your background in the app is loaded separately by the app and images usually load in the background with a delay - make sure the image loading happens on UI thread, blocking the UI thread until the image is loaded, so a UI without the image does not show up.
2. A system tray at the top of the screen will shift the contents of your application down by 72 pixels. You can either hide the tray or make it transparent and adjust your background by setting the margin to -72,0,0,0.
3. Is the effect you wish to achieve worth the effort and the risks of performance degradation and having your app killed by the OS due to blocking of the UI thread if loading of the image and decoding takes longer than usual (common when loading things from Flash memory)?

Comment: A system tray meanin the appbar or the status bar which has the battery and signal? The status bar is 32pixels and the appbar is 72 right? Yes I do hav an appbar and it looks like, as you have said, the elements gets pushed down. Hide which tray? the one on top?

Comment: Its a calendar sorta appication and everydate has a bg. I have set the build action to content so that it doesn take a lot of time to load.

Comment: I meant the system tray at the top. Could be wrong about the size. You can set its opacity to 0, so it will be transparent and your background will still be visible underneath, but you might need to tweak the margins to make it slide underneath the tray. The content vs. resource option does not matter here - you need to decode it blocking the UI anyway when the app starts, so it does not matter which way it is stored, since it loads from Flash at app start either way.

Comment: Had similar problem and solved it by setting the opacity of the system.tray to 0 (transparent). this should fix it for you.